# Changing the fontsize of annotation in R plotly

Tags: r, graphics, annotations, font-size, r-plotly

I would like to increase the size of text annotations on plotly figure. The solution I came up is on the below minimal code. However, once the number of digits increase through the value, the font size of text is not applied into all digit members in the same way. In order to show you the actual issue, I prepare a pseudo input data, so please do not concentrate on why there some silly numbers to be displayed. This issue looks a small point, but it heavily affects my fluctuated data visualisation which have various deep and top values in the sequence. Any idea about this?

**Minimal code**

```
library(plotly)

df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- df[which(df$year==2007 & df$continent=='Europe' & df$pop > 2.e6),]

#pseudo input data
temp_data <- c(c(1:5, 10:15, 100:105, 1000:1010))

fig <- plot_ly(df, type='bar', x = ~country, y = temp_data, text = temp_data, name="",
               textposition = 'outside', #'auto' 
               textangle    = -90,
               textfont     = list(size = 120)
               )

fig
```

**Current output**

[image]

**The expectation is something like that**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using `layout`. To accommodate the numbers, I also increased the y axis range.

```r
library(plotly)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'plotly'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     last_plot
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     layout

df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- df[which(df$year==2007 & df$continent=='Europe' & df$pop > 2.e6),]

#pseudo input data
temp_data <- c(c(1:5, 10:15, 100:105, 1000:1010))

fig <- plot_ly(df, type='bar', x = ~country, y = temp_data, text = temp_data, name="",
               textposition = 'outside', #'auto'
               textangle    = -90) %>% layout(yaxis=list(range=c(0, max(temp_data)+200)),
                                              uniformtext=list(minsize=18, mode='show'))
fig
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is absolutely perfect answer! It is exactly what I would like to see.

Comment: Glad it works for you. Maybe you could still rotate the annotation and X axis labels in the same direction, though...

Comment: I figured out the adaption of your suggestion into my code without any issue. So entire rotations and labels are fine. However, I am not sure whether I really understand what you have planned and coded in the layout section :( For instance the aim of +200 ? The purpose of uniformtext is key here ?

Comment: If you leave out the 200, your y axis goes to 1000, and the labels are cut off. So increasing the Y range will give you some more space. uniformtext allows you to adjust the font size (see: https://plotly.com/r/text-and-annotations/#controlling-text-fontsize-with-uniformtext)